# Rust type that requires manual drop

Tags: rust, ownership

Is there a way to have the Rust compiler error if a struct is to be automatically dropped?

Example: I'm implementing a memory pool and want the allocations to be manually returned to the memory pool to prevent leakage. Is there something like `RequireManualDrop` from the below example?

```rust
impl MemoryPool {
   pub fn allocate(&mut self) -> Option<Allocation> { /* ... */ }
   pub fn free(&mut self, alloc: Allocation) { let (ptr, size) = alloc.inner.into_inner(); /* ... */ }
}

pub struct Allocation {
   inner: RequireManualDrop<(*mut u8, usize)>,
}

fn valid_usage(mem: &mut MemoryPool) {
   let chunk = mem.allocate();
   /* ... */
   mem.free(chunk);
}

/* compile error: Allocation.inner needs to be manully dropped */
fn will_have_compile_error(mem: &mut MemoryPool) {
   let chunk = mem.allocate();
   /* ... */
}
```

Comment: If you write a `Drop` implementation for `Allocation`, won't that take care of it? Regardless of whether the drop happens explicitly, or automatically when the allocation goes out of scope?

Comment: You might be interested in [`std::mem::ManuallyDrop`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/mem/struct.ManuallyDrop.html).

Comment: @Thomas that makes the Allocation need to have a back reference to MemoryPool then you need synchronization logic in addition to that if Allocation implements Send.

Comment: @Aiden4 that appears to only prevent the Drop implementation from running rather than enforce a compiler error when a type falls out of scope without being handled.

Comment: Maybe related but not useful: https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/68318

Comment: @Thomas This is not related; this feature is about coherence.

Comment: It's related insofar as that `impl !Drop for Allocation {}` is forbidden, or will soon be.

Comment: https://gankra.github.io/blah/linear-rust/ discuses the challenges of adding support for this kind of thing.

Comment: @JeffMuizelaar Linear types are related but not the same: most discussions around linear types in Rust assume `Drop` should be the way to drop, not some custom function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rust doesn't have a direct solution for this. However, you can use a nit trick for that (this trick is taken from https://github.com/Kixunil/dont_panic).

If you call a declared but not defined function, the linker will report an error. We can use that to error on drop. By calling an undefined function in the destructor, the code will not compile unless the destructor is not called.

```rust
#[derive(Debug)]
pub struct Undroppable(pub i32);

impl Drop for Undroppable {
    fn drop(&mut self) {
        extern "C" {
            // This will show (somewhat) useful error message instead of complete gibberish
            #[link_name = "\n\nERROR: `Undroppable` implicitly dropped\n\n"]
            fn trigger() -> !;
        }
        unsafe { trigger() }
    }
}

pub fn manually_drop(v: Undroppable) {
    let v = std::mem::ManuallyDrop::new(v);
    println!("Manually dropping {v:?}...");
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=01f8e871d0d0a633ad59a59b00a8d1a9).

However, beware that while in this case it worked even in debug builds, it may require optimizations in other cases to eliminate the call. And unwinding may complicate the process even more, because it can lead to unexpected implicit drops. For example, if I change `manually_drop()` to the following seemingly identical version:

```rust
pub fn manually_drop(v: Undroppable) {
    println!("Manually dropping {v:?}...");
    std::mem::forget(v);
}
```

It doesn't work, because `println!()` may unwind, and then `std::mem::forget(v)` won't be reached. If a function that takes `Undroppable` by value must unwind, you probably have no options but to wrap it with `ManuallyDrop` and manually ensure it is correctly dropped (though you can just drop it at the end of the function, and let the unwind case leak it, as leaking in panicking is mostly fine).

Comment: Thank you, this is really helpful. I think I'll use this hack behind a feature flag which can be use to test correctness.

Comment: I don't think there is an advantage to use a feature flag, unless optimizations are required, then you can use `#[cfg(debug_assertions)]` that (almost) detects optimized builds.

Comment: Yeah I was thinking I didn't want to have this hack in production but if it were compiled it would have a compile error. So in that regard it's fine. Playing around with it now, dealing with potential unwinds might make this too much of a pain.